# How to convert a row (array of strings) to a dataframe column

Tags: arrays, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with only one column and one row of array of strings, for example:

```
   +---------------------------------------+
   |     col1                              |
   +---------------------------------------+
   |[st1,  st2, st3, st4, st5, st6,  st7...|
   +---------------------------------------+
```

I want to convert it to a new dataframe with again one column but many rows which each row has one of the entries in the array of string, as bellow:

```
   +-----------+
   |     col1  |
   +-----------+
   | st1       |
   +-----------+
   | st2       |
   +-----------+
   | st3       |
   +-----------+
   | st4       |
   +-----------+
   | st5       |
   +-----------+
   | st6       |
   +-----------+
   | st7       |
   +-----------+
   | ...       |
   +-----------+
   | ...       |
   +-----------+
```

Any suggestion is appreciated.

```
   scala> df.printSchema
      root
         |-- col1: array (nullable = true)
         |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

Comment: *****Solution*****   var df = df.withColumn ("col1", explode("col1"))